# Collada Armature Export

Tags: armature, export, collada

I am having trouble with exporting a rigged model to Collada. It mostly exports correctly with exception for objects which use armature. I baked the animation for all the bones, so there are no constraints involved anymore. The armature object itself, is parented to a non-armature parent object, and has no keyframes (if I try to bake object keyframes for it, it wipes the bone animation)

Here's how it looks before the export
[image: The setup prior to export]

And here's what it looks like after reimporting it back in Blender. As you can see, the tool attachment which originally uses armature has gone frantic and is displaced all over the scene.
[image: The setup after exporting and reimporting via Collada]

The bone animation has exported, but all the geometry is skewed and/or offset. I can't make any sense of it. FBX export comes out even worse.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the objects causing problem then hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then `Apply location`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this unfortunately doesn't do the trick. Ultimately it just gave me a different flavor of "messed up".

Comment: @BaconBad could you please provide your .blend file to be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes i fix that kind of issues with alt+s; alt+r and alt+g, you can try that, then apply (Ctrl+A) location, rotation and location.
I mean after you re-imported (excuse my english)

Comment: Good to know! I ended up fixing this issue by using .fbx instead, and making sure to use the correct export arguments.